# List in certain range

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate that is supposed to form a list from list, taking into a new list only these numbers that are in a certain range. The predicate works, but suppose that I want to get a list not including bounds. 
So I change the condition `A >= L, A =< R` to `A > L, A < R`, but then I only get "True", and Prolog outputs nothing.

What could be a problem here?

My code is:

```
range([], _, _, []).
range([A|L1], L, R, [A|L2]) :- 
    A>L,
    A<R,
    range(L1, L, R, L2).

range([A|L1], L, R, L2) :- 
    A=<L;
    A>=R,
    range(L1, L, R, L2).
```

This is what program outputs:

```
range([1,2,3,4,5], 1,4, X).
?- range([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 1,3, X).
true .
```

This is what I want it to output:

```
?- range([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 1, 5, X).
X = [2,3,4] .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot needed parenthesis

```
range([A|L1], L, R, L2) :- 
    ( A=<L ; A>=R ),
    range(L1, L, R, L2).
```

otherwise, when `A=<L`, you loose the recursive call, and then variables remain not instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Priority of the conjunction and disjuntion, `,` and `;`, makes it necessary to write the third clause as:

```
range([A|L1], L, R, L2) :- 
    (   A=<L
    ;   A>=R
    ),
    range(L1, L, R, L2).
```